# Visual Studio 2010 Open Containing Folder Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When trying to use the Open Containing Folder from Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 64-bit, I get the following error about half the time:

Unable to open the folder. It might have been deleted or existing permissions might be insufficient.

Does anyone have a fix for the problem?  I've made a workaround in the following macro:

```
Public Sub OpenContainingFolder()
    Shell("""C:\Windows\explorer.exe"" /select,""" + DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName + "", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this has been open for so long, I'm sticking with the workaround:

```
Public Sub OpenContainingFolder()
    Shell("""C:\Windows\explorer.exe"" /select,""" + DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName + "", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
End Sub
```